# ASP.NET AJAX AutoComplete Extender Scrolling Issue

Tags: asp.net-ajax, autocompleteextender

I was looking at the ASP.NET AJAX AutoComplete Extender sample on http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Once the items are populated in the list the scrolling doesn't seem to work in IE8 but it works in IE7. How can I make the scrolling work in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE8 here, tried on 2 machines.  I don't think the issue is with the control, perhaps you have something else running that's affecting it?